# adding quotes to the arraylist received from android to PHP

Tags: php, android

I have an array with 400 values and i am sending using the volley.

```
ArrayList<String> aa= new ArrayList<>();
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put("arr", aa.toString());
            return params;
         }
```

And i am able to receive the value in php.

```
$list[] = $_POST['arr'];
```

The values looks like [value1,value2,value3]. how to add the double quotes to this to look like ('value1','value2','value3'). Tried with implode but it is not working.

Tried with JSON also

```
JSONimdb = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {

        try {
            JSONimdb.put("genere"+String.valueOf(i+1), aa.get(i));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then sent to php

```
ArrayList<String> aa= new ArrayList<>();
@Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        params.put("arr", JSONimdb.toString());
        return params;
     }
```

Received in php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

when i iterate the values using foreach the $data looks empty. So i stick with the arraylist method only. Help me with the besy way.

Comment: Change the Android code to send the array as JSON. Then `json_decode` the string on the PHP side.

Comment: yes tried with JSON. Received the objects $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); but not able to convert it into ('value1','value2','value3').  format. so i stick with this.